# Sets constructed by random variable series limit

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

Let $(\Omega$, $\mathcal{F}$, $P)$ be a probability space, $X_n$, $X$ random variables in that space. Show that:

$(a)$ $\{\omega\in\Omega| \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} X_n(\omega)$ $exists\}\in\mathcal{F}$,

$(b)$ $\{\omega\in\Omega| \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} X_n(\omega)=X(\omega)\}\in\mathcal{F}$.

Edit:

I found quite simply solution.

$\{\omega\in\Omega| \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} X_n(\omega)exists\}=\\=\{\omega\in\Omega| \forall_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\exists_{N\in\mathbb{N}}\forall_{m,n>N}|X_n(\omega)-X_m(\omega)|<\frac1k\}= \\=\bigcap\limits_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\bigcup\limits_{N\in\mathbb{N}}\bigcap\limits_{n,m>N}\{|X_n(\omega)-X_m(\omega)|<\frac1k\}=\\=\bigcap\limits_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\bigcup\limits_{N\in\mathbb{N}}\bigcap\limits_{n,m>N}\big(\{X_n(\omega)-X_m(\omega)<\frac1k\}\cap\{X_n(\omega)-X_m(\omega)>-\frac1k\}\big)\in\mathcal{F}$

Comment: Can you show that $\limsup_n X_n$ is measurable (and $\liminf$)? If so, the set of points at which the limit exists can be written as the set of points satisfying $\limsup_n X_n(\omega) = \liminf_n X_n(\omega)$.

Comment: Is $\{\omega|\lim\sup_nX_n(\omega)>a\}=\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\{\omega|X_n(\omega)>a\}$ enough to show that $\lim\sup_nX_n$ measureable?

Comment: That is not a correct equality.

Comment: It should be $\{\omega|\sup_{k\geq n}X_k(\omega)>a\}=\bigcup\limits_{k=n}^{\infty}\{\omega|X_k(\omega)>a\}$ right? And then by $\limsup_nX_n=\lim_n\sup_{k\geq n}X_k$ we got that $\limsup_nX_n$ is measureable.